# How to match 01-47

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I have to grep some log files.

so I code this

```
 egrep [0-4][0-7] log
```

bug this code has a bug for
08,09,18,19,28,29,38,39

Can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|` allows you to specify alternatives in a regex.

```
0[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-7]
```

Comment: On the command line, you need to single-quote this expression, to protect the shell special characters, especially `|`. In fact, it is a good habit to always single-quote your regular expressions on the command line.